# Lego 42129 automatic suspension lift

Tags: technic, powered-up, remote-control, set-modification, control-plus

Has anyone looked at a mod to lower the suspension on the LEGO 42129 4x4 Mercedes-Benz trail truck when the differential lock activates.

I was thinking about a few linear Actuators but never had a set with them in so I also wondered how much power they can take and apply?

Can linear actuator be operated from both ends, i.e. if you push down on the extended rod, will the lower shaft rotate or is power transfer just one way?

I hope some can help, even if it's just with info

Answer (score 1):

A linear actuator cannot be operated both ways, and cannot replace a strut with a spring. It can only be driven through the gearing input to extend or retract.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using actuators to replace the damper/strut. But thanks for the information about actuators

Comment: Is there a set number of rotations the lower gear goes through to fully extend/retract the actuators do you know?

Comment: 5.2 rotations for the small ones

Comment: They all seem to be 5.2 rotations per stud, from memory I believe it's only .5 of a rotation to lock the differential,if in correct please feel free to correct. So I've got to transfer. 5 a rotation  to maximum of 41.6 rotations